# Julia: join two matrices using the same memory

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to fuse two arrays without using more memory, it's posible?, for instance:

```
a=[1 2 3
   4 5 6
   7 8 9]
b=[11 12 13
   14 15 16
   17 18 19]
```

I need to get the array:

```
c=[a b]
```

but using the same memory as `a` and `b`, i.e, any change in `a` or `b` must be reflected in `c`.

Comment: Does [LazyArrays](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/LazyArrays.jl) do what you want? If not, you'd probably need to implement your own custom type, which could be simple if all you care about is indexing, but more involved if you want to apply fancier operators...

Comment: I don't know, I should check it out. In general, what I want is to avoid using more memory, since my arrays are larger

Comment: Do you really need the `c` array? That is, do you need to perform array operations on `c`? Otherwise perhaps simply a tuple of `(a, b)` might be good enough to keep the arrays together.

Comment: Why do you want to reuse the same memory? If it's because you want the operation to be fast, you might be better off creating a new array. As efficient array operations assume the arrays are laid out continuously, column-first, in memory.

Comment: I really needed to have `c` of the same type as `a` and `b`, using the same memory, but it seems that it is not possible.

Comment: As another comment points out, you can trivially just create a tuple of `a` and `b`. So really, this question is not answerable until you tell us *exactly* what you want to be able to do with `c`.

Comment: There are several things that I needed to do, one would be to transfer the data to a GPU, i.e. to have the data together there, I think I should look for other alternatives, the `LazyArrays` package will help me in some points, in general I think the question was answered, `LazyArrays` and `CatViews` packages do a good job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also another package [CatViews.jl](https://github.com/ahwillia/CatViews.jl)

```
julia> x = CatView(a, b);   # no copying!!!

julia> reshape(x, size(a, 1), :)
3×6 reshape(::CatView{2,Int64}, 3, 6) with eltype Int64:
 1  2  3  11  12  13
 4  5  6  14  15  16
 7  8  9  17  18  19
```

Comment: very interesting, but I needed to perform some operations on `x`, it doesn't allow me to use some functions

Comment: It would be helpful to know **which** operations you want to perform on `x`. Otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: It isn't necessarily fast, though, if that's what the OP is after.

Comment: ideally it would be to have `x` of the same type as `a` and `b`, but it seems that it is not possible, although this is the closest to what I wanted.

Comment: This is probably a consequence of methods that are overly-specific about their input arguments. For example, there is only rarely a reason to write `foo(m::Matrix)` instead of `foo(m::AbstractMatrix)`, yet you find the former in code all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you start in reverse, define `C` first

```
julia> C = rand(0:9, 3, 6)
3×6 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  2  4  4  9  8
 8  8  6  5  5  9
 0  7  5  8  7  5
```

then have `A` and `B` be `view`s of `C`

```
julia> A = @view C[:, 1:3]
3×3 view(::Array{Int64,2}, :, 1:3) with eltype Int64:
 3  2  4
 8  8  6
 0  7  5

julia> B = @view C[:, 4:6]
3×3 view(::Array{Int64,2}, :, 4:6) with eltype Int64:
 4  9  8
 5  5  9
 8  7  5
```

then it works.

```
julia> A[2,2] = -1
-1

julia> C
3×6 Array{Int64,2}:
 3   2  4  4  9  8
 8  -1  6  5  5  9
 0   7  5  8  7  5
```